¿Datos extraídos limitados sobre AWS Textract?
Estoy trabajando con la api AWS Texctract para extraer los datos de un pdf pero textract sólo devuelve las 4 primeras páginas, mis pdf no tienen más de 8 páginas y no superan el límite de 500mb, ¿alguna idea?
Number of pages is detected
Cut on the 4th page

Necesito saber si hay algo que causa esto o si es sólo un problema con mi código.

